# Powershell Add Domain Controller Name to CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a small error in my CSV.  I'm just trying to get my CSV to kick out the properties listed for a user and a last column stating the specific DC from which it pulled that data:

```
$Path = Get-ScriptDirectory
$Date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$Domain = Get-ADDomain | select -ExpandProperty ParentDomain
$DomainName = Get-ADDomain | select -ExpandProperty NetBIOSName
$Filename = "$Path\$DomainName" + "_Users_By_Last_DC_" + $Date + ".csv"
$DClist = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | select name
$Statement = ForEach ($DomainController in $DClist){
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName, DisplayName, LastLogonDate, LogonCount, Enabled, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordNotRequired, CannotChangePassword, AccountExpirationDate, AccountExpires, WhenCreated, canonicalName -Server $DomainController.Name | select SamAccountName, DisplayName, LastLogonDate, LogonCount, Enabled, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordNotRequired, CannotChangePassword, AccountExpirationDate, AccountExpires, WhenCreated, canonicalName, @{Name="Domain Controller";Expression=$DomainController.name} | sort $DomainController.name, samAccountName, LastLogonDate}

$Statement | Export-Csv $FileName -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm getting for 'Domain Controller' the following:
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

I feel like adding an `-expandproperty name` would be appropriate, but I can't seem to figure out where it would go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `Expression` entry in a calculated property must be a `ScriptBlock`. Change:

```
@{Name="Domain Controller";Expression=$DomainController.name}
```

to

```
@{Name="Domain Controller";Expression={$DomainController.Name}}
```

Putting the list of properties in an array may also help you read and maintain your script better:

```
$Properties = @(
    'SamAccountName', 
    'DisplayName', 
    'LastLogonDate', 
    'LogonCount', 
    'Enabled', 
    'PasswordExpired', 
    'PasswordLastSet', 
    'PasswordNeverExpires', 
    'PasswordNotRequired', 
    'CannotChangePassword', 
    'AccountExpirationDate', 
    'AccountExpires', 
    'WhenCreated', 
    'canonicalName' 
)
$DCName = $DomainController.Name

$Select = $Properties + @{Name="DomainController";Expression={$DCName}}
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $Properties -Server $DCName| Select $Select | sort DomainController,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate
```

Comment: Was your college major Being Awesome, or were you just born that way?  Thanks!

Comment: @NateR np. And no, I dropped out of high school to study the subtle art of solving real-world problems, worked out pretty well :D